# MySQL SQL query with AVG over a DISTINCT, CONCATted date column

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I have got following data in a MySQL table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM reading LIMIT 0,10;
+----+---------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | date                | power | temperature |
+----+---------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | 2011-02-15 21:58:41 |   124 |          22 |
|  2 | 2011-02-15 21:58:47 |   123 |          22 |
|  3 | 2011-02-15 21:58:53 |   124 |          22 |
|  4 | 2011-02-15 21:58:59 |   686 |          22 |
|  5 | 2011-02-15 21:59:05 |   126 |          22 |
|  6 | 2011-02-15 21:59:11 |   123 |          22 |
|  7 | 2011-02-15 21:59:17 |   122 |          22 |
|  8 | 2011-02-15 21:59:47 |   122 |          22 |
|  9 | 2011-02-15 21:59:59 |   122 |          22 |
| 10 | 2011-02-15 22:00:29 |   123 |          22 |
+----+---------------------+-------+-------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

*(it is not a secret these are readings from Current Cost device)*

Now, I have been battling SQL for few hours to get a average power amount over a 15 minutes period.  The closest I could get is:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT( 
        DATE(date), ' ',
        HOUR(date), ':',
        CASE
            WHEN MINUTE(date) BETWEEN  0 AND 14 THEN '00'
            WHEN MINUTE(date) BETWEEN 15 AND 29 THEN '15'
            WHEN MINUTE(date) BETWEEN 30 AND 44 THEN '30'
            WHEN MINUTE(date) BETWEEN 45 AND 59 THEN '45'
        END
    ) AS date,
    ROUND(AVG(power),1)
FROM reading
WHERE date > '2011-02-20' AND date < '2011-02-21'
GROUP BY date;
```

Which gives me result as following:

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     CONCAT( 
    ->         DATE(date), ' ',
    ->         HOUR(date), ':',
    ->         CASE
    ->             WHEN MINUTE(date) BETWEEN  0 AND 14 THEN '00'
    ->             WHEN MINUTE(date) BETWEEN 15 AND 29 THEN '15'
    ->             WHEN MINUTE(date) BETWEEN 30 AND 44 THEN '30'
    ->             WHEN MINUTE(date) BETWEEN 45 AND 59 THEN '45'
    ->         END
    ->     ) AS date,
    -> ROUND(AVG(power),1)
    -> FROM reading
    -> WHERE date > '2011-02-20' AND date < '2011-02-21'
    -> GROUP BY date LIMIT 0,10;
+-----------------+---------------------+
| date            | ROUND(AVG(power),1) |
+-----------------+---------------------+
| 2011-02-20 0:00 |               320.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:00 |               319.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:00 |               317.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:00 |               313.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:00 |               315.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:00 |               315.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:00 |               320.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:00 |               315.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:00 |               315.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:00 |               313.0 |
[...]
| 2011-02-20 0:45 |               316.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:45 |               311.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:45 |               310.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:45 |               317.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:45 |               311.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:45 |               312.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:45 |               318.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:45 |               315.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:45 |               313.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:45 |               316.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:45 |               311.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:45 |               312.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:45 |               319.0 |
| 2011-02-20 0:45 |               312.0 |
[...]
| 2011-02-20 4:00 |                95.0 |
| 2011-02-20 4:15 |                95.0 |
| 2011-02-20 4:15 |                95.0 |
| 2011-02-20 4:15 |                94.0 |
| 2011-02-20 4:15 |                94.0 |
| 2011-02-20 4:15 |                94.0 |
| 2011-02-20 4:15 |                94.0 |
| 2011-02-20 4:15 |                94.0 |
| 2011-02-20 4:15 |                94.0 |
| 2011-02-20 4:15 |                96.0 |
| 2011-02-20 4:15 |                93.0 |
| 2011-02-20 4:15 |                94.0 |
| 2011-02-20 4:15 |                93.0 |
| 2011-02-20 4:15 |                93.0 |
+-----------------+---------------------+
10 rows in set, 1 warning (0.20 sec)
```

Which is still quite far away from what I am trying to get.  It seems like I am very close to what I need, just something to DISTINCT the date field and get averages from all equal dates fields, but I just can't get the correct SQL.

The result I am aiming for is something along lines:

```
| 2011-02-20 4:00 |                94.0 |
| 2011-02-20 4:15 |               194.3 |
| 2011-02-20 4:30 |               197.4 |
| 2011-02-20 4:45 |               145.3 |
| 2011-02-20 5:00 |                94.0 |
| 2011-02-20 5:15 |                96.0 |
| 2011-02-20 5:30 |                93.0 |
| 2011-02-20 5:45 |                94.0 |
```

Any help or hints much appreciated.

Comment: Counting averages over groups and then average once more can give you wrong results, for example average of (2, 6, 10) is 6, but if you try counting sub-averages you can get avg(4,10)=7 or avg(2,8)=5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is getting confused because you've aliased your `CONCAT()` output to the same name as an existing column, so `GROUP BY date` is grouping by the *table's* date field, not your rounded-to-the-nearest-15-minutes date.

You'll need to change your query to something like

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     CONCAT( 
    ->         DATE(date), ' ',
    ->         HOUR(date), ':',
    ->         CASE
    ->             WHEN MINUTE(date) BETWEEN  0 AND 14 THEN '00'
    ->             WHEN MINUTE(date) BETWEEN 15 AND 29 THEN '15'
    ->             WHEN MINUTE(date) BETWEEN 30 AND 44 THEN '30'
    ->             WHEN MINUTE(date) BETWEEN 45 AND 59 THEN '45'
    ->         END
    ->     ) AS quarterhour,
    -> ROUND(AVG(power),1)
    -> FROM reading
    -> WHERE date > '2011-02-20' AND date < '2011-02-21'
    -> GROUP BY quarterhour LIMIT 0,10;
```

Also, instead of `HOUR()` I would use `DATE_FORMAT()` in order to zeropad the hours, otherwise "5" (5AM) comes after "17" (5PM).

`CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:'), CASE ... END)` should do the job.

Comment: Thanks DerfK - that did the job!